# Group by period

Tags: group-by, odoo, odoo-8

I am working on Odoo 8 and I have a model that has two date fields (check_in and check_out). I  need to perform a group by month filter, but i want records that have different months for their check_in and check_out for example (11/04/2022 - 12/05/2022) to appear on each month when doing the group by filter

Answer (score 0):

In your `group_by` filter you can use `:date_type` in order to specific how to group by date.

For example:
`<field name="context">{'group_by':'check_in:month'}</field>`